# How to replace elements within a pandas dataframe column according to an ordered list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, append

Lets say  I have this pandas dataframe:

```
index  a        b
1    'pika'   'dog'
2    'halo'   'cat'
3    'polo'   'dog'
4    'boat'   'man'
5    'moan'   'tan'
6    'nope'   'dog'
```

and I have a list like this:

`colors = ['black' , 'green', 'yellow']`

How would I replace all the `dog` in column `b` with the elements

in the `colors` list in the **same order**?

Basically, I want it to look something like this:

```
index  a        b
1    'pika'  'black'
2    'halo'   'cat'
3    'polo'  'green'
4    'boat'   'man'
5    'moan'   'tan'
6    'nope'  'yellow'
```

Comment: If there's a fourth "dog", what would you want it to become?  "black", or "dog", or NaN?

Comment: There won't be a fourth dog. The length of the dog's will be the exact same as the colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and Boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['b'].eq('dog'), 'b'] = colors

print(df)

   index     a       b
0      1  pika   black
1      2  halo     cat
2      3  polo   green
3      4  boat     man
4      5  moan     tan
5      6  nope  yellow
```

Comment: Nice, so simple :) Overthought the process, +1

Answer (score 0):

Another way using numpy put

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['pika', 'halo', 'polo', 'boat', 'moan', 'nope'],
                   'b': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'man', 'tan', 'dog']})
colors = ['black' , 'green', 'yellow']
```

df

```
    a       b
0   pika    dog
1   halo    cat
2   polo    dog
3   boat    man
4   moan    tan
5   nope    dog
```

-

```
# 'wrap' mode is not needed when replacement list is same
# size as the number of target values
np.put(df.b, np.where(df.b == 'dog')[0], colors, mode='wrap')
```

df

```
    a       b
0   pika    black
1   halo    cat
2   polo    green
3   boat    man
4   moan    tan
5   nope    yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.cycle`, `df.apply`, and  `lambda`

```
In [100]: import itertools as it

In [101]: colors_gen = it.cycle(colors)

In [102]: df1['c'] = df1['b'].apply(lambda x: next(colors_gen) if x == 'dog' else x)

In [103]: df1
Out[103]:
      a    b       c
0  pika  dog   black
1  halo  cat     cat
2  polo  dog   green
3  boat  man     man
4  moan  tan     tan
5  nope  dog  yellow
```

This will also work for larger `DataFrames`

```
In [104]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['pika', 'halo', 'polo', 'boat','moan','nope','etc','etc'], 'b':['dog','cat','dog','man','tan','dog','dog','dog']})

In [106]: df2['c'] = df2['b'].apply(lambda x: next(colors_gen) if x == 'dog' else x)

In [107]: df2
Out[107]:
      a    b       c
0  pika  dog   black
1  halo  cat     cat
2  polo  dog   green
3  boat  man     man
4  moan  tan     tan
5  nope  dog  yellow
6   etc  dog   black
7   etc  dog   green
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with

```
n=(df.b=="'dog'").sum()

df.loc[df.b=="'dog'",'b']=(['black' , 'green', 'yellow']*(n//3))[:n]
```